# Terminal shows black screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bash, gnome-terminal, dash-shell

When I open the terminal in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it shows a black window with no buttons. Nothing's visible, not even the minimise or close button. However all the commands that I type, work perfectly. If I click at the position where the close button should be, it closes. Without the terminal, I cant run any of the command line programs.

This problem has been there ever since I ran the janitor from inside ubuntu-tweak. I deleted cache for chromium and firefox and some other files that I don't remember now. I had removed Unity a year back and have Gnome desktop environment installed. Please help.

Comment: I'd always read that Ubuntu-Tweak was a dangerous tool & shouldn't be used, I guess this is one reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Janitor seems to purge a lot of packages according to this answer:

[How safe is Ubuntu tweak's Janitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234740/how-safe-is-ubuntu-tweaks-janitor/234792#234792)

Post #6 from this link could be helpful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1925476&p=11695832#post11695832

To list all packages that were removed you can use this command (quoted from link mentioned above):

`grep 'remove' /var/log/dpkg.log`

To install those packages automatically you could use a tool like `sed` to transform the output of given command to a suitable format for installing it with `apt-get`.

Or use `cut` and `xargs` like:

`grep 'remove' /var/log/dpkg.log | cut -d " " -f 4 | xargs -I {} apt-get install {}`

To avoid prompts you could use this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
grep 'remove' /var/log/dpkg.log | cut -d " " -f 4 | xargs -I {} apt-get -y install {}
```

Of course if you want to see the commands you are typing you could as a temporary solution use a virtual console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.