# Ubuntu Tweak is no longer maintained?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-tweak

Looks like Ubuntu Tweak project is no longer maintained and the application is no longer available through PPA. I particularly loved the Janitor feature in Ubuntu Tweak. Are there any alternatives one can use?

Source - [Ubuntu Tweak in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak)

Answer (score 2):

if you are familiar with the command line you can do exact the same thing yourself with a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/234792/354350
**BUT** be careful and you should know what you are doing, because some commands use [superuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)-rights!
...maybe write a little script and everything is done with just one click! ;-)

---

**anyway i would recommend to use [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/)**: it's a good file-cleaner with a GUI and (also in superuser-mode) you can hardly mess up your system.

open your terminal and just type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bleachbit`, type your password (no characters will be displayed) and wait till executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unity-tweak-tool` to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak had this Janitor, that I found particularly useful. Is there any tool that does similar things?

Comment: @jaibatrik... I have found the terminal commands to be useful and quick: autoremove and autoclean. Synaptic is very good to repair broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning is your objective, you have many options. Bleachbit is great. Nautilus has addons [use Synaptic to install these]. In terminal, you have autoremove and autoclean.